# Why is git push work differently than git push origin <branch>?

Tags: git, aws-codecommit

Why are these two commands producing these results:

1. (master is checked out)
   git checkout beta
   git push
2. (beta is checked out)
   git push origin beta

I ask because the former results in an error (403) in AWS CodeCommit, and the latter pushes to the branch just fine. Also, I get a warning whenever I checkout beta that I'm +20 commits ahead of the origin branch:

"Your branch is ahead of 'codecommit-origin/beta' by 38 commits."

Comment: The cause of this issue was because when I was checked out to master, the remote URL was correct, but when I was checkout out to beta, the remote URL changed to the http version of the URL, not the correct ssh version.

Correcting the URL (git remote set-url --push <url>) fixed this, and leads me to believe that the URL of remote depends on which branch is checked out, making the 1st scenario and 2nd scenario different.

Answer (score 1):

Note: this answer is for `git push` in general and not for git with AWS

`git push` takes in as arguments where you want to send the code (origin), and the branch that you are sending the code from. Thus, if you see in many code examples, `git push origin master` pushes code to `origin` from your `master` branch. If you enter the command `git push origin beta`, then you push to the `beta` branch of the remote `origin` repository from your local `beta` branch. `git checkout` is a command that switches the branch you are currently working in. Thus, `git checkout beta` switches your local repository to the `beta branch`, and if you make changes and commit them (make sure to commit before switching branches!) they will only change in the `beta` branch. Likewise, `git checkout master` switches to your master branch. It does not matter what branch you run `git push` from, since you specify which branch to push as the second argument.

Comment: Why should I type in the "origin" argument? Why can't I use "git push beta" instead of "git push origin beta"? Is there a way to push somewhere else except origin?

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with your git config `push.default` setting. To see your settings run:

`$ git config -l`

(keep in mind you can have 3 different git settings: global, system, local. Run the above command with either `--global` `--system` or `--local` to see the values set for each.)

If you just use `git push` but don't specify **where** you are pushing to, git will use the rules for the `push.default` setting. To avoid unintended behavior, always be verbose and specify where you want to push to, ie: `git push origin beta`

[git push.default documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pushdefault)